# Javascript get the value of an href after a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like `https://www.whatever.com/en-CA/something` I want to capture anything that comes **after** the `en-CA/` (the en-CA can be any combination of characters that have two letters, a dash, and two letters.

I am trying to use a regex to

1. grab the window.location.href
2. split the href at the pattern that matched the /en-CA/
3. take the remainder of the href

   ```
   window.location.href.split(/^(\/[a-zA-Z]{2})(-)([a-zA-Z]{2}\/)$/[1].match(/.*/)
   ```

I dont think i quite have the right setup here. How do I accomplish grabbing everything after the `/character character dash character character /`

Comment: Only the `CA` part of the `en-CA` will change right?

Comment: despite you use location.href / separate match / many regex group. I don't see why it would not working.

Comment: is it not an option to use `window.location.pathname` and then simply split on `/`? or will you need query options as well?

Comment: oh and it would also fail if there is another match in path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution

```js
const url = "https://www.whatever.com/en-CA/something";
const result = url.split(/\/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}\//i)[1];

if (!result) throw new Error("Invalid url");

console.log(result);
```